# Error in NIntegrate command

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate (numerically) the integral $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dx\,dy\,dz\,ds\,dt\,du}{(x - s)^2 + (y - t)^2 + (z - u)^2}$$ with *Mathematica* using the following

```
NIntegrate[1/((x - s)^2 + (y - t)^2 + (z - u)^2), 
    {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

but surprisingly, it keeps giving me a negative answer!
It would be highly appreciated, if someone could give an alternative method (command) to evaluate this integral.

Comment: Why are your limits in your code not the same as in the problem?

Comment: Not that this should affect the sign, but which set of limits are you trying to impose?

Comment: made corrections.thanks.

Comment: Isn't the issue that this integral diverges very badly around the xyzstu origin?

Comment: ...and any time `x == s && y==t && z==u`.

Comment: ...actually, any time `x == s OR y == t OR z == u`.

Comment: I am almost certain that it converges.(it is governed by $\int_{\|A\|\leq R}\int_{\|B\|\leq R}\frac{1}{|A|}dV(A)dV(B)$)

Comment: I'm kind of concerned by the fact that `Integrate[1/((x - s)^2 + (y - t)^2 + (z - u)^2), x]` evaluates quickly but `Integrate[1/((x - s)^2 + (y - t)^2 + (z - u)^2), {x,0,1}]` can be done by hand before *Mathematica* finishes.

Comment: After one iteration we will end up with an expression involving arctan and things get nasty thereon...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not confident of this answer, but it seems worth presenting:

`NIntegrate[2^3/((x - s)^2 + (y - t)^2 + (z - u)^2),
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {s, 0, x}, {t, 0, y}, {u, 0, z}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 16] // Quiet`

(* 5.63378 *)

The basic insight is that each "paired" integrations (e.g., $x$ and $s$; $y$ and $t$; $z$ and $u$) is over the unit square.  Each such pair can be replaced by a symmetric integration over *half* that square (e.g., $0 < x < 1$ with $0 < s < x$).  Thus there will be an undercounting of $2^3 = 8$.

One can extend this core idea to integrating each "pair" of variables over a smaller portion of their respective unit square and multiply the overall integral accordingly.

Anyway... perhaps this will point others in the proper direction.

---

I now believe my answer is correct.

Here is why:  Make a change of variables:  $a = x - s$; $b = y - t$ and $c = z - u$.  Then the integral over the unit square defined by $x$ and $s$ can be recast as a one-dimensional integral over the new variable $0 \le a \le 1$.  However, there is a scaling factor that is needed which you can see if you draw the unit square and consider symmetry.  There is hence a factor of $2 (1 - a)$ and likewise for the $b$ and $c$ variables.

`NIntegrate[(8 (1 - a) (1 - b) (1 - c))/(a^2 + b^2 + c^2), 
    {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 16]`

(* 5.63371 *)

---

If someone has the time, he or she could go one step further and replace the integration over the cube defined by $a$, $b$ and $c$ to a one-dimensional integration over a variable $q$ that goes on the diagonal of that cube, from $(a,b,c) = (0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$.  Be careful with scaling and normalization.  If we're lucky, we might get a closed-form answer (presumably involving inverse trigonometric functions).  Here's a figure illustrating the new variable $q$ in red:

[image]

Wouldn't that be cool?   A six-dimensional numerical integration replaced by a one-dimensional symbolic integration?!

Answer (score 7):

I'm 95% confident that David G. Stork's answer is in the ballpark:

```
n = 100000000;
x = RandomReal[1, n]; y = RandomReal[1, n]; z = RandomReal[1, n];
s = RandomReal[1, n]; t = RandomReal[1, n]; u = RandomReal[1, n];
r = 1/((x - s)^2 + (y - t)^2 + (z - u)^2);
xbar = Mean[r];
xsd = StandardDeviation[r];
lowerCL = xbar - 1.96 xsd/n^0.5;
upperCL = xbar + 1.96 xsd/n^0.5;

{lowerCL, upperCL}

(* {5.60976, 5.66793} *)
```